# What to do when Windows 8 cannot save the bug check dump?

Tags: windows, windows-8, crash

I have a system where 30-40% of the time it wakes up from sleep and bug checks on me (DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE). However, I believe this error has to do with the hard drive because no matter what I do, I cannot get it to save anything from the bug check. No matter what dump option I pick, there is no dump saved, nor does it record any entry in the Event Log.

If my assumption is correct, I cannot get any details from the bug check to help me narrow down the driver (i.e. is it the hard drive firmware itself, or the SATA controller drivers, etc.).

I've tried windows update and updating all of my drivers but everything claims they're all up to date.

Is there something I can do to get it to print more of the bug details to the screen, since nothing will log?

Comment: It still might have saved some details in the system event log, check there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enabled the pagefile and if you set to genretae complete dumps, make sure it has the size of your RAM + a few MB. This is required to get dumps.

if you get the dumps, [Install Windbg](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-23-Windows-8-SDK) and [debug the dump yourself](http://www.codemachine.com/article_debugging0x9F.html).

Here are additional data about [the bugcheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).